# ajax request adding url paratemeters

Tags: ajax

I'm unsure if I'm just thinking of this the wrong way of thinking or I'm just missing something.

I have a search box that does some wildcard searches in a database. I have made this an ajax request so I don't need to reload the page and I can have a little please wait icon while the data loads.

Now as there is pagination so I could do with the url parameters being added to the url, can you do this on a ajax request, ad if so how?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code (param1) :

```
data    : $('#form-contactSupplementaire').serialize() + "&param1=value",
```

Request full ajax :

```
$.ajax({
            method  : "POST",
            url     : "...",
            data    : $("...").serialize() + "&param1=value",
            dataType: "",
            success : function (json) {
                // ...
                console.log(json);
            }, error: function () {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
```